# React-Native Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'

Tags: java, android, react-native

Whenever I try to run 'react-native run-android'

I got failure:

Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'

I tried checkout to previus commits.
I tried removing android/app/build and re-build
I tried removing debug.keystore and initiated it again.

none of them solved the problem.

I successfully run my app before in android virtual device, and I've already uploaded my app to google play store, and it works.

I haven't seen this error before. My code worked totally fine before:

- I removed some font files in android/src/main/assets/fonts. This maybe the reason.
- I ran "react-native run-ios". This may be the reason.

> Task :app:packageDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
117 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 112 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

  > 4 exceptions were raised by workers:
  >   java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Execution of compression failed.
  >   java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Execution of compression failed.
  >   java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Execution of compression failed.
  >   java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Execution of compression failed.

BUILD FAILED in 22s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
at runOnAllDevices (/Users/leonkong/Desktop/dev/CoddingHippo/Native_Makkcha/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
at buildAndRun (/Users/leonkong/Desktop/dev/CoddingHippo/Native_Makkcha/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:158:41)
at then.result (/Users/leonkong/Desktop/dev/CoddingHippo/Native_Makkcha/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:125:12)
```

Build Success message. And running app on virtual device  by android studio 2

Answer (score 4):

- Clean Gradle

  cd android

  ./gradlew clean

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted my computer and ran ./gradlew assembleRelease again in the project's android folder and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I also face issue.

I just open Android Studio - Clear Build - Run app.

Works for me

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps

1. Uninstall app from emulator
2. Remove build from android
3. Run `./gradlew clean in android`
4. Run `react-native start --reset-cache`
5. Run `react-native run-android`

It worked for me